# Чем именно является this?

Tags: javascript, this

Чем именно является this в JS? Переменной, хранящей ссылку на объект, самим объектом или это что-то иное?

Если у нас есть подобный объект:

```
let user = {
 //Что угодно
}
```

в переменной 'user', по сути, хранится не сам объект, а ссылка на него.
В переменной this хранятся ссылки на разные объекты, или он сам становится объектом и хранит в себе свойства?

Comment: [this в JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
P.S. Еще есть очень много статей на хабре на этой теме

Comment: "Контекстный объект JavaScript, в котором выполняется текущий код. " https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this